# How to convert seconds to HH:mm to HH:mm:ss in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Suppose I have a time as `13:45`.

Now I want to convert this into `13:45:00` using moment.js.

I am doing 
`moment('13:45').format('h:m:s');` but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `moment` constructor to create a object then use `format()`

```js
console.log(moment('13:45', 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add second parameter to let moment know the format of your passed date

```
moment('13:45', 'HH:mm').format('h:m:s')
```

or

```
moment('13:45', 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm:ss')
```